# The pseudo-class (:active) does not work for the menu of my Wp theme

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, pseudo-class

I bought a theme **(HelpGuru)** and I have a problem with the css of menu .
I contact the support but they can not help me. They simply directed me to a company that personalizes wordpress themes.
Here is the link of : https://demo.herothemes.com/helpguru/

I would like the menu to indicate the tab corresponding to the displayed page.
**For example :**
when I am on "Home page" display the link "HOME" of the underlined menu or in another color.
Normally we use the pseudo-class **:active**. But it does not work.
i looked on the internet, I saw that there was an possibility to do this by Php.

**Is it possible to do that by CSS and how?**

Thank you so much for your help.
Best regards.
Zed

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBkJ1.jpg)

Comment: can you share your URL with us? it is impossible to say something without seeing that menu in action

Comment: The `:active` *pseudo-class* requires activation from the end-user, some sort of interaction, it is not an automatic assignment. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active. Wordpress, on the other hand, automatically assigns specific classes to menu items of the currently viewed page.

Comment: I work locally on a virtual machine.
The menu is the same on démo. please see attached screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I checked out the website, in the menu, the link of the page that is active has the class `current-menu-item`, hence you can use this class and styles.

Below are two methods to add underline effect.

```
.current-menu-item{
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

OR

```
.current-menu-item{
    border-bottom:1px solid #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Great ! It works.
Thank you very much to Naren Murali 
Have a great weekend